# indexed tables don't seem to accelerate query performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm working with `postgres`, but the index subject seems to fit for `sql` as well

I have 2 tables:

table A:

```
name, id, geom, value, desc
```

where:

```
geom is type of geometry

geom is indexed as geom_index
```

table B:

```
 lnn_name, geom
```

where:

```
geom is type of geometry

geom is indexed as geom__lnn_index
```

I checked the performance of the following query:

```
select desc, sum((st_distance(A.geom, B.geom)<300)::INT) as res
from tblA as A, tblB as B
where A.geom is not null
group by A.desc
```

**The time to calculate the query seems the same with or without index**

Why the index don't help to reduce the time to calculate the query ?

I expect that geom will be save in a way which can reduce the query time (long distances between points will be ignored automatically)

Comment: "I expect that geom will be saved in a way that can reduce the query time..."  No.  All an index does is save the same information in a different order.  There may be databases that help with distance calculations, but that's not the task of an index,

Comment: Two things - how many rows? And second - look at the query plan to see if they are different and how its being resolved.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is saying:

1. Create a Cartesian product between the two tables.
2. One column then filters this Cartesian product based on distance.

However, the *overall* query is not doing any significant filtering.  If you want the indexes to be used, try putting the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
select desc, count(*) as res
from tblA A join
     tblB B
     on st_distance(A.geom, B.geom) < 300
where A.geom is not null
group by A.desc;
```

Now the query is saying to filter the results from the `join` data *before* aggregating.

Comment: Is it possible to add to your answer query the count of A.geom which are not nulls ?

Comment: @user3668129 . . . That would require a `left join` and that might, in turn, cause problems with the index.  What does a `left join` do to the performance of the query?